# Data submission not working while using Swing application otherwise it works normally

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-handling

When i write PreparedStatement in main function, it works perfectly and submits the data but when i write in in actionPerformed function it doesn't work, why??
I don't think I'm doing anything wrong.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class EnterData {

    static void insertData(int rn, String fn, String ln) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {    
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentinfo","root","12345")) {
            String query = "insert into student (rollno, fname, lname)" + " values (?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setInt (1, rn);
            preparedStmt.setString (2, fn);
            preparedStmt.setString (3, ln);
            preparedStmt.execute();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Submit Information");
        mainFrame.setSize(400, 300);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setLayout(null);

        JLabel heading = new JLabel("Enter Data");
        heading.setBounds(150, 10, 100, 20);
        mainFrame.add(heading);

        JLabel rollnoLabel = new JLabel("Roll Number");
        rollnoLabel.setBounds(70, 60, 100, 20);
        mainFrame.add(rollnoLabel);
        JTextField rollno = new JTextField();
        rollno.setBounds(220, 60, 100, 20);
        mainFrame.add(rollno);

        // Taking First Name
        JLabel name1 = new JLabel("First Name");
        name1.setBounds(70, 110, 100, 20);
        mainFrame.add(name1);
        JTextField fname = new JTextField();
        fname.setBounds(220, 110, 100, 20);
        mainFrame.add(fname);

        // Taking Last Name
        JLabel name2 = new JLabel("Last Name");
        name2.setBounds(70, 160, 100, 20);
        mainFrame.add(name2);
        JTextField lname = new JTextField();
        lname.setBounds(220, 160, 100, 20);
        mainFrame.add(lname);

        // Submit and Reset Button
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit.setBounds(70, 220, 100, 20);
        mainFrame.add(submit);
        JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
        reset.setBounds(220, 220, 100, 20);
        mainFrame.add(reset);

        // Frame Visibility
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    int rn = Integer.parseInt(rollno.getText());
                    String fn = fname.getText();
                    String ln = lname.getText();

                    insertData(rn, fn, ln);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Submitted Successfully...!!!", "Submission Prompt", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.err.println("Got an exception!");
                    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried this and it works perfectly but when i put those statements in actionPerformed function they don't work.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentinfo","root","12345");

            String query = "insert into student (rollno, fname, lname)" + " values (?, ?, ?)";

            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setInt (1, 6505);
            preparedStmt.setString (2, "Prince");
            preparedStmt.setString (3, "Saini");

            preparedStmt.execute();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception!");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try to submit them via the GUI? What type of error are you seeing?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not seeing any error due to catch block. It says got an exception com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Comment: That ***is*** an error, and it's **very** important -- perhaps you will want to post the complete error message / exception stacktrace with your question, no? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Also within the catch block, have: `e.printStackTrace();` where `e` is whatever you name the exception variable

Comment: Not related to the current problem, but important in any case: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).